# Need clarification on copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a question about when the copy constructor in C++ would be called from the perspective of the code snippet given below:

```
bool do_stuff(int a, int b, char *c, Uid key = 0);
```

Here `key` is the default argument to `do_stuff()`

```
class Uid {
...
...
private:
    u_char data_[UID_LENGTH];
}
```

Now, `Uid` has these constructors:

```
Uid:Uid()
{
    memset(data_, 0, UID_LENGTH);
}

/// @brief Copy construct a uid
Uid::Uid(const Uid &id)
{
    memcpy(data_, id.data_, UID_LENGTH);
}

/// @brief Copy the contents of ptr as the contents of a new Uid
Uid::Uid(const u_char* ptr)
{
    memcpy(data_, ptr, UID_LENGTH);
}

/// @brief Set the contents of a Uid with provided values
Uid::Uid(u_int64_t high, u_int64_t low)
{
 …
 …
}
```

When `do_stuff` is called with three arguments, `Uid::Uid(const u_char* ptr)` is getting called to create the object for `key`. Is it due to lack of a better match that `Uid::Uid(const u_char* ptr)` is selected?

Would changing the prototype to...

```
bool do_stuff(int a, int b, char *c, Uid key = (Uid)0);
```

...ensure that `Uid::Uid(const Uid &id)` gets called?

Thanks!

Comment: This really doesn't have much to do with copy constructors.

Comment: How is `Uid` constructed taking an `int`? For the moment it looks `Uid(char*)` is called from the default value.

Comment: You know, I typed my answer and then realized, I don't see what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve. Why are you even passing 0 as the default argument?

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm passing 0 as a default value to the argument. And that results in a crash when the third constructor gets called. So I wanted to know how I could avoid this situation and invoke the other constructors instead.

Comment: Yes, I can see you pass 0. The question was why on earth you pass 0.

Comment: @StoryTeller It was a mistake and I paid the price for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do

```
bool do_stuff(int a, int b, char *c, Uid key = Uid{});
```

This way the default constructor will be called if you call `do_stuff` with three input arguments.

Comment: This did not work for me. Got compilation errors as follows. Line 42 is the same as what you suggested:  `default_constructor.cc:42: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
default_constructor.cc:42: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
default_constructor.cc:42: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token`

Comment: @Maddy - It ought to be `Uid key = Uid{}`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is allowed to elide the copy constructor when making the default Uid argument. To see this, recompile your program (assuming g++) with `-fno-elide-constructors` to see the difference.

Regarding the `Uid::Uid(char const*)` constructor, it *is* the best match for `0` since it still is usable as a `nullptr` when you currently have no constructors that take a scalar value.